# Graph-based News Feed & Activity Log

Tags: database-design, graph, neo4j, cypher, feed

For a few days, I've been working on developing a Newsfeed using the Neo4j Graph Database and toying around with various ways of including an Activity Log (similar to Facebook) that will keep track of every user action.

For example, User1 sends a friend request to User2 (which would translate to something like this in Cypher):

```
MATCH
    (me:User {username: 'john.snow@gmail.com'}), 
    (friend:User {username: 'arya.stark@gmail.com'})

WHERE 
    NOT (me)-[:FRIENDSHIP_UPDATE]-(:FriendshipStatus)-[:FRIENDSHIP_UPDATE]-(friend)

CREATE
    (me)-[:FRIENDSHIP_UPDATE]-(friendshipStatus:FriendshipStatus {status: 0})-[:FRIENDSHIP_UPDATE]->(friend)

RETURN
    me,
    friendshipStatus,
    friend
```

Pretty basic stuff so far, just create 2 relationships and 1 node that contains all the information regarding their friendship.

Retrieving both outgoing and incoming events is also pretty simple:

```
MATCH
    (me:User {username: 'john.snow@gmail.com'})-[actionName]->(actionData)-[]->(friend:User)

RETURN
    me,
    type(actionName) AS actionName,
    actionData,
    friend

UNION MATCH
    (me:User)<-[actionName]-(actionData)<-[]-(friend:User)

RETURN
    me,
    type(actionName) AS actionName,
    actionData,
    friend
```

But, let's say User2 declines User1 friend request, which would end up deleting the entire relationship between them. No problem... for a simple notification panel (like "you have one friend request", the other cancels the friend request, "oups, no friend requests"). So, no history.

Like I said, I'm planning to do something like the Facebook Activity Log.

```
> You liked [User]'s*link to the user* [Photo]*link to the photo* at [Time].
> [User]*link to user* declined your friend request at [Time].
> You sent [User]*link to user* a friend request at [Time]
```

I've toyed with various ways of doing this, including linked lists, down to the day. The days would then contain the events the user performed or has been exposed to in that particular day (when creating an event, it is pushed to the friend timeline also - see the second code block) and keeping direct relationships between user (friendship updates, likes, etc) for speed so I don't have to search thru all the Day nodes.

Edit: Forgot to mention why I didn't stick with that particular design.

The problem was that there was no similarity between the actions (for example a "like" is directed to a "post" while a "friendship request" is directed to a "user"), which made me end up with multiple, unwanted joins.

What would be a good database design to keep track of all these actions, even if they get deleted?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A useful event log must not delete any log entries and must reliably return entries with their original data. Essentially, log entries are static data that must never change, once created.

1. Probably the best solution would be to maintain a separate "log DB" (perhaps not even a graph DB) of log entries for all events. This will keep your "live data" DB simpler, and your logging mechanism will also be simpler.
2. If you wanted to use the same neo4j DB for the log entries, you could keep it in a separate "log subgraph" that is disjoint from your "live data subgraph" (i.e., no shared nodes, and no relationships between "log nodes" and "live nodes" -- although log properties can contain identifying info about live data). The reason it has to be disjoint is because live data can change at any time (e.g., nodes/relationships can be deleted, properties can change, etc.), but a log entry must still be able to return the data state that applied at the time the entry was created. This approach may be more effort than it is worth, though.